# on android 14, overridePendingTransition work wrong

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-14, overridependingtransition

I tried to implement activity to activity transition with animation,
so I used overridePendingTranstiion.
and I find some very weird issue.
[this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvRs9.gif)
occur when I remove any obsolete xml file that placed in res/anim directory.
I tested many devices, this issue only occurs on android 14 devices.
and this issue disappear after restarting device.
is there anyone else experienced similar problem?
please excuse my poor english.

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpejn.gif) animation is normal result.

I used animation below animation xml named 'slide_in_left'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@integer/animation_default_duration"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

and, I used this like below.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java))
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method was deprecated in API level 34.
Use [overrideActivityTransition(int, int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#overrideActivityTransition(int,%20int,%20int)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This method was deprecated in API level 34. Use [overrideActivityTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#overrideActivityTransition(int,%20int,%20int))

```
public void overrideActivityTransition (int overrideType, 
                int enterAnim, 
                int exitAnim)
```

Comment: targetSdkVersion of mine is 33. I can't not use that on current version.
is there any reason that overridePendingTransition was deprecated?